# How to automate local tests against different dependency versions (using composer)?

Tags: php, testing, composer-php, automated-tests

I have an app which must work with a specific package in various versions. 
I'd like to automatically run local tests against different versions of the package.

How is it done?

I can think of a manual way:

- change composer.json
- run `composer update`
- run tests
- repeat with another version

**Update:**

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7081#issuecomment-364049067), I can just pull another version on top of an existing composer.json:

- `composer require vendor/package:$(MY_PACKAGE_VERSION)`
- run tests
- pull another version

But one must be careful because you are messing with a working copy of the app. As [ob-ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2184166/ob-ivan) suggested to clone the app in another place, pull new version and perform tests over there.

Comment: I wonder if running tests locally is the best approach for this goal. Do you want it for the test-first development process?

Comment: I want to make sure different versions of a package do not conflict with my app's code before pushing to a repo. When I change app I'd like to perform tests against all supported versions of the package. Running local tests is the fastest route to detecting issues, right?

Comment: **If** you can get it to work faster than deploying to a build server, then yes. One may find it easier to set up Jenkins/Bamboo/Travis etc for this kind of task. Alternatively, the manual process you described can be automated with a shell script. Its only disadvantage is that it leaves your working copy in a potentially modified state. My suggestion is that the script checks out your repo to a temporary directory and runs there. But care should be taken to clean up neatly if the script interrupts (ctrl+c? system outage? fatal error?).

Comment: I believe I can sketch one, but this would require a sample repo to run it against. Do you mind providing one?

Comment: Sure, this repo https://github.com/lezhnev74/apideveloperio-laravel. See `illuminate/support` dependency, it can be as 5.5+ as well as 5.4+.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by this question, I have developed a utility just for that purpose.

Introducing DiversiTest: https://github.com/ob-ivan/diversitest

Its primary advantage over running tests in a CI server is that it allows you to test your work in progress before you commit, or even before you code --- for example, if you don't want to make an explicit commit after creating red tests in your TTD process.

### How to use

Install by `composer require ob-ivan/diversitest`

Add a configuration file like follows:

```
# diversitest.yaml
package_manager: 'composer require $package $version'
test_runner: 'vendor/bin/phpunit'
packages:
    illuminate/support:
        - 5.4.*
        - 5.5.*
```

And run with:

```
vendor/bin/diversitest
```

This copies your working directory to a temporary folder and loops into installing dependencies versions and running tests with commands provided by config.

Note that if you list several packages each with a list of versions, it will go through a cartesian product of all supplied `package:version` pairs.

The utility is still at development stage, feature requests and bug reports are welcome on GitHub issues page.